# Posting a gist to github.com in ruby not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, http-post, gist

I am trying to create a new gist on github.com by posting the the URL. I have done this in C# and it works fine, but when I try to replicate in ruby on rails the post never seems to work I am always just redirected to the gists/new URL which indicates that the post was not accepted. I figure I am just missing something fundamental in ruby.

```
require 'net/https'
require 'open-uri'

url = URI.parse('https://gist.github.com/gists')

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.form_data = "file_name[gistfile1]=testclip.txt&description=Test Clip&file_contents[gistfile1]=This is my test clip&login=uname&token=secret"
http.start{|h| h.request(req)}['Location']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm out on a limb here, but I'm guessing it has to do with the SSL verify mode. You'll either need to keep from verifying:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

or give it something to verify against:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(ca_cert)
```

Take a look at [the `ca_cert` method at Defunkt's Gist gem](https://github.com/defunkt/gist/blob/master/lib/gist.rb#L239) for more info (you'll need [a bundle](https://github.com/defunkt/gist/blob/master/lib/gist/cacert.pem)).

Comment: I did try the VERIFY_NONE option. I would think that if it were a verification problem the post wouldn't even happen. The post is happening, but it seems as if the data is not getting written.

Comment: Interesting, especially since [everything else looks right](https://github.com/defunkt/gist/blob/master/lib/gist.rb#L111-129). =\